# After jQuery load(), jQuery click handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a click function on the HTML page for DIV elements. But after using jQuery load(), that click function for the DIV elements does not work. For example:

```
$(".about .visible").click(function () {
$("form").toggleSlide();
});
```

```
<div class="mypro"> 
<div class="about">
<div class="visible"></div>
here is my text
</div>
</div>
```

If I use:

```
$(".mypro").load("get.php");
```

Actually this is the original code:

```
$('.cv-right .cv-right-content .about').on({
mouseenter: function (a) {
     $(this).find('.about .visible').show();
},
mouseleave: function (a) {
    $(this).find('.about .visible').hide();
}

});
```

Then, jQuery code for `.about .visible` click will not work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The load tag is not for the kind of load you are discussing here. Please always read tag descriptions to see if they are appropriate before you add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delegate event to handle dynamic elements:

```
$(".mypro").on("click", ".about .visible", function () {
    $("form").toggleSlide();
});
```

Comment: $(".about").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(".visible",this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(".visible",this).hide();
    }
});

Comment: Describe not working. Error in console or what happen? BTW, what means your first comment here?

Comment: It is like jquery breaks. every jquery code till this div(div .about) works. but after this div does not work when I load("get.php")

Comment: You have to debug it. If any js stop working, i guess you have one or more unhandled exception

Comment: Ok, and how can I do it ? Is there any example or document ?

Comment: If you are completly new in browser developement, then see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code Otherwise i'm sorry, i didn't understand what you meant

Comment: please, can you give example for unhandled exception ?

Comment: No, i cannot give you example of unhandled exception... Open your console and see if there is error.

Comment: I looked everything, but could not find anything. console did not give any error. may be I have to put the whole code here ?

Comment: I found, I used $(document). But there is another problem. when I click submit button inside .about the second time it goes to the action file. But it must not do it

Comment: I think you are binding submit event and preventing default behaviour. If ya, you have to delegate submit event too.

Comment: Aha, I understand. Thank you for help, if there will be any other problem (possibly will be). I will write here

Comment: @CavidKərimov No, for other issue, please consider to ask a new specific question